# Fetch rows from pandas dataframe based on fixed counts from first row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's my dataframe with 2500 rows.[image: Dataframe]

This is the index of my dataframe

```
Index([u'Volume(%)1', u'Height(um)1', u' Area(%)1', u'OffsetX(mm)1',
       u'OffsetY(mm)1', u'Volume(%)2', u'Height(um)2', u' Area(%)2',
       u'OffsetX(mm)2', u'OffsetY(mm)2',
       ...
       u'Volume(%)499', u'Height(um)499', u' Area(%)499', u'OffsetX(mm)499',
       u'OffsetY(mm)499', u'Volume(%)500', u'Height(um)500', u' Area(%)500',
       u'OffsetX(mm)500', u'OffsetY(mm)500'],
      dtype='object', length=2500)
```

I want to group all Volume,Height,Area,OffsetX,OffsetY rows separately for analysis.

Kindly help on how to proceed further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping rows (or columns) separately, in order to analyze is doing what pandas refers to as [**split-apply-combine**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)

**Setup Example Data**

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

np.random.seed([3,14159])

idx = pd.Index([
    u'Volume(%)1', u'Height(um)1', u' Area(%)1', u'OffsetX(mm)1',
    u'OffsetY(mm)1', u'Volume(%)2', u'Height(um)2', u' Area(%)2',
    u'OffsetX(mm)2', u'OffsetY(mm)2', u'Volume(%)499', u'Height(um)499',
    u' Area(%)499', u'OffsetX(mm)499', u'OffsetY(mm)499', u'Volume(%)500',
    u'Height(um)500', u' Area(%)500', u'OffsetX(mm)500', u'OffsetY(mm)500'],
    dtype='object')

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20, 6), idx)
```

I'm going to take the tack of assuming you want to group by the first portion of the index string prior to the parentheses.  In that case, we can do this

```
# split part of split-apply-combine
g = df.groupby(df.index.str.strip().str.split('(', 1).str[0])
```

This can now be used to perform all normal group by operations

```
g.mean()

                0         1         2         3         4         5
Area     0.570096  0.442108  0.483907  0.369207  0.296919  0.504575
Height   0.717268  0.681560  0.584143  0.707477  0.675091  0.519428
OffsetX  0.382745  0.341273  0.583181  0.581414  0.483730  0.389093
OffsetY  0.544904  0.429652  0.226045  0.458973  0.688739  0.499085
Volume   0.526659  0.404874  0.472162  0.618568  0.255428  0.748262
```

Or an aggregation with `agg` (I use `stack` below for display purposes)

```
g.agg(['mean', 'sum', 'max']).stack()

                     0         1         2         3         4         5
Area    mean  0.570096  0.442108  0.483907  0.369207  0.296919  0.504575
        sum   2.280386  1.768432  1.935627  1.476826  1.187676  2.018299
        max   0.802345  0.699236  0.885809  0.855904  0.533728  0.596097
Height  mean  0.717268  0.681560  0.584143  0.707477  0.675091  0.519428
        sum   2.869072  2.726240  2.336572  2.829906  2.700365  2.077713
        max   0.922273  0.964951  0.951598  0.922242  0.975507  0.892488
OffsetX mean  0.382745  0.341273  0.583181  0.581414  0.483730  0.389093
        sum   1.530979  1.365093  2.332724  2.325658  1.934922  1.556371
        max   0.933637  0.630542  0.928255  0.944937  0.713851  0.844690
OffsetY mean  0.544904  0.429652  0.226045  0.458973  0.688739  0.499085
        sum   2.179618  1.718607  0.904180  1.835893  2.754955  1.996340
        max   0.923857  0.765601  0.715871  0.818813  0.802785  0.676706
Volume  mean  0.526659  0.404874  0.472162  0.618568  0.255428  0.748262
        sum   2.106637  1.619497  1.888647  2.474271  1.021713  2.993047
        max   0.665079  0.595963  0.726680  0.948864  0.453699  0.940529
```

---

We can sharpen up the grouping by implementing a `lambda` as opposed to using a series of `str` accessor functions.

```
g = df.groupby(lambda i: i.strip().split('(', 1)[0])
```

Not only is this shorter, it's also quicker if barely.

```
%timeit df.groupby(df.index.str.strip().str.split('(', 1).str[0]).agg(['mean', 'sum', 'max'])
%timeit df.groupby(lambda i: i.strip().split('(', 1)[0]).agg(['mean', 'sum', 'max'])

5.7 ms ± 211 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
5.06 ms ± 94.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) first and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with some aggregation, e.g. `mean`:

```
a = pd.Index([u'Volume(%)1', u'Height(um)1', u' Area(%)1', u'OffsetX(mm)1',
       u'OffsetY(mm)1', u'Volume(%)2', u'Height(um)2', u' Area(%)2',
       u'OffsetX(mm)2', u'OffsetY(mm)2'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(10)}, index=a)
print (df)
              a
Volume(%)1    0
Height(um)1   1
 Area(%)1     2
OffsetX(mm)1  3
OffsetY(mm)1  4
Volume(%)2    5
Height(um)2   6
 Area(%)2     7
OffsetX(mm)2  8
OffsetY(mm)2  9    

a = df.index.str.extract('(Volume|Height|Area|OffsetX|OffsetY)', expand=False)
print (a)
Index(['Volume', 'Height', 'Area', 'OffsetX', 'OffsetY', 'Volume', 'Height',
       'Area', 'OffsetX', 'OffsetY'],
      dtype='object')

df = df.groupby(a).mean()
print (df)
           a
Area     4.5
Height   3.5
OffsetX  5.5
OffsetY  6.5
Volume   2.5
```

---

If you want extract all values separately and create `MultiIndex` with 3 levels:

```
a = (df.index
      .to_series()
      .str.extract('(Volume|Height|Area|OffsetX|OffsetY)(\(.*\))(\d+)', expand=True))
print (a)
                    0     1  2
Volume(%)1     Volume   (%)  1
Height(um)1    Height  (um)  1
 Area(%)1        Area   (%)  1
OffsetX(mm)1  OffsetX  (mm)  1
OffsetY(mm)1  OffsetY  (mm)  1
Volume(%)2     Volume   (%)  2
Height(um)2    Height  (um)  2
 Area(%)2        Area   (%)  2
OffsetX(mm)2  OffsetX  (mm)  2
OffsetY(mm)2  OffsetY  (mm)  2

df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([a[0], a[1], a[2]], names=('a1','b1','c1'))
print (df)
                a
a1      b1   c1   
Volume  (%)  1  0
Height  (um) 1  1
Area    (%)  1  2
OffsetX (mm) 1  3
OffsetY (mm) 1  4
Volume  (%)  2  5
Height  (um) 2  6
Area    (%)  2  7
OffsetX (mm) 2  8
OffsetY (mm) 2  9
```

---

```
df = df.groupby(level='a1').mean()
#from 0.20.1+
#df = df.groupby('a1').mean()
print (df)
           a
a1           
Area     4.5
Height   3.5
OffsetX  5.5
OffsetY  6.5
Volume   2.5
```

Very similar solution if need 3 columns from `Index`:

```
a = (df.index
      .to_series()
      .str.extract('(Volume|Height|Area|OffsetX|OffsetY)(\(.*\))(\d+)', expand=True))
a.columns = ['a1','b1','c1']
print (a)
                   a1    b1 c1
Volume(%)1     Volume   (%)  1
Height(um)1    Height  (um)  1
 Area(%)1        Area   (%)  1
OffsetX(mm)1  OffsetX  (mm)  1
OffsetY(mm)1  OffsetY  (mm)  1
Volume(%)2     Volume   (%)  2
Height(um)2    Height  (um)  2
 Area(%)2        Area   (%)  2
OffsetX(mm)2  OffsetX  (mm)  2
OffsetY(mm)2  OffsetY  (mm)  2

df = a.join(df)
print (df)
                   a1    b1 c1  a
Volume(%)1     Volume   (%)  1  0
Height(um)1    Height  (um)  1  1
 Area(%)1        Area   (%)  1  2
OffsetX(mm)1  OffsetX  (mm)  1  3
OffsetY(mm)1  OffsetY  (mm)  1  4
Volume(%)2     Volume   (%)  2  5
Height(um)2    Height  (um)  2  6
 Area(%)2        Area   (%)  2  7
OffsetX(mm)2  OffsetX  (mm)  2  8
OffsetY(mm)2  OffsetY  (mm)  2  9
```

---

```
df = df.groupby('a1').mean()
print (df)
           a
a1          
Area     4.5
Height   3.5
OffsetX  5.5
OffsetY  6.5
Volume   2.5
```